# System call level is not correct

Tags: delphi, winapi, shfileoperation

I'm using SHFileOperation to delete files to Recycle bin. But sometimes I received a "System call level is not correct" error. It not happens every time or every file. Just some random files at random time. Anyone knows the reason? Thanks.

**Update**: Here it the code I am using:

```
function DeleteToRecycleBin(const ADir : WideString) : Integer;
var
  op : SHFILEOPSTRUCTW;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@op, sizeof(op));
  op.pFrom := PWideChar(ADir + #0#0);
  op.wFunc := FO_DELETE;
  op.fFlags := FOF_SILENT or FOF_NOCONFIRMATION or FOF_NOERRORUI or FOF_ALLOWUNDO;
  Result := SHFileOperationW(op); 
end;
```

Comment: Most likely when the files are in use, [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925124/error-deleting-folder-bin-the-system-call-level-is-not-correct) may be helpful.

Comment: No, I can manually delete them to recycle bin

Comment: You could try repeating the problem with the antivirus real time checking turned off.

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving error code 124 (0x7C).  Win32 error code 124 is `ERROR_INVALID_LEVEL`.  However, if you read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164.aspx) for `SHFileOperation()`, some of its error codes pre-date Win32 and thus do not have the same meaning as the same Win32 error codes.  Error code 124 is one of those values.  In the context of `SHFileOperation()`, error 124 actually means:

> DE_INVALIDFILES 0x7C
>
> The path in the source or destination or both was invalid.

**Update**: try this:

```
function DeleteToRecycleBin(const ADir : WideString) : Integer;
var
  op : SHFILEOPSTRUCTW;
  sFrom: WideString;
begin
  // +1 to copy the source string's null terminator.
  // the resulting string will have its own null
  // terminator, effectively creating a double
  // null terminated string...
  SetString(sFrom, PWideChar(ADir), Length(ADir)+1);
  
  ZeroMemory(@op, sizeof(op));
  op.pFrom := PWideChar(sFrom);
  op.wFunc := FO_DELETE;
  op.fFlags := FOF_SILENT or FOF_NOCONFIRMATION or FOF_NOERRORUI or FOF_ALLOWUNDO;
  
  Result := SHFileOperationW(op); 
end;
```

Comment: I'm trying to delete files to recycle bin and there is a message box to indicate that the access is denied. But I can manually delete the files to recycle bin. So, I guess source path should be valid.

Comment: @trudger But Windows thinks otherwise. Have you confirmed the exact paths being passed in?

Comment: Please show your actual code, and actual values being passed to `SHFileOperation()`.

Comment: @Remy Here it is 
  op : SHFILEOPSTRUCTW;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@op, sizeof(op));  
  op.pFrom := PWideChar(ADir + #0#0);
  op.wFunc := FO_DELETE;
  op.fFlags := FOF_SILENT or FOF_NOCONFIRMATION or FOF_NOERRORUI or FOF_ALLOWUNDO;
  Result := SHFileOperationW(op);

Comment: @trudger: Next time, edit your original post to add updates. I have done it for you. You did not show what the actual value of `ADir` is, though.

Comment: @trudger: `op.pFrom := PWideChar(ADir + #0#0);` allocates a temporary `String` that may go out of scope, freeing the `String` and leaving `op.pFrom` pointing at invalid memory, before `SHFileOperation()` is called. Try using a local variable instead: `var sFrom: string; sFrom := ADir + #0#0; op.pFrom := PWideChar(sFrom);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have updated the code again and show the complete function. The ADir is a parameter passed in and I think it should be valid in the whole function scope.

Comment: @trudger: But you are appending characters to `ADir`, which will allocate a new `WideString`. You still have not shown what **the value of `ADir`** is. That is what `SHFileOperation()` is complaining about.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I see, thanks for the explanation. I'll try it out and post back. As for the ADir, it has no specified value. The error just occurred on random path.

Comment: @trudger: what is the actual value when it fails?  You need to get that info for your own troubleshooting.