# Cant run UWP App with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I am creating new UWP Project. For the first time I run the app everything works fine. After I try to run it again I am getting error as below:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Error : DEP0500 : The folder "C:\Users\xxxx\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\UWPTest\UWPTest\bin\x86\Debug\AppX" could not be deleted. 
Access to the path 'UWPTest.exe' is denied. UWPTest
```

Did anyone has similar issue? What to do ?

Comment: Looks like the app process is still running. Did you close the application instance first? Otherwise try just deleting `/bin` folder and its content and run again

Comment: I cannot delete /bin  errir - 'call level system is not corred'

Comment: Microsoft isn't going to fix that error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925124/error-deleting-folder-bin-the-system-call-level-is-not-correct/5925141

Comment: So problem is with Visual Studio or with Windows or what?

Comment: The problem described in the OP is related to Visual Studio (once out of 50 times is occurring for me too), but I've never heard of the error deleting the folder which it always work for me

Comment: maybe the problem occur because of the developer option on windows 10, have you changed it to developer mode? maybe windows update changed it back. tried checking it.