# c# "the system call level is not correct" on getFiles of a folder

Tags: c#, file, getfiles

i need read all files txt in a folder on this address: 192.168.1.209\user\HST.
This is my c# code:

```
string str = "";
        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\192.168.1.209\user\HST\");
            FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.txt");

            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                str = str + ", " + file.Name;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception pp)
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(GlobalVariables.errorFolderLocation + "erroreLettura.1.209.txt", pp.ToString());
        }
```

This code get me this error: "the system call level is not correct".
The strange thing is that if i read another file, for example: 192.168.1.201\user\HST it works.

I would like to specify that i can see all files txt inside the folder.
Another strange thing is that i can't see the size of the folder like this image:
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQcY8.png)

So, i ask you, how can i resolve this problem? How can i read files inside this folder? Is there a similar function that allows me to read all files?

Answer (score 0):

take a time to verify if

- The remote network pc file system if is NTFS,
- If the file is not used/locked by an other process
- Follow this link: [error-deleting-folder-bin-the-system-call-level-is-not-correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925124/error-deleting-folder-bin-the-system-call-level-is-not-correct/43548245)

Comment: one of my tests was delete the folder and create another with the same name because 
I thought that the file was corrupt. So when i tried to delete it, i get this error: 
"File is used by another process". So I think that the problem is this. Is there a way to get around this, and read the folder?